# style sheet -moz-linear-gradient no show in web mobile browser?

Tags: css, stylesheet

I have a sample code:

```
<div class="title"><h3>Test Title<h3></div>
```

And css

```
.title {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #6F6F6F 0%, #4E4E4E 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

When I browser as PC is result OK, but when using mobile phone (samsung galaxy S3, iPhone 4) result not show this style, How to fix it ?

Comment: Try to add one more `-webkit-linear-gradient`, and read about [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/linear-gradient).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is your using the vendor prefixes -moz zo only a browser thats reading -moz wil work with this

this are the types to use:

```
-moz-linear-gradient
-webkit-linear-gradient
-o-linear-gradient
-ms-linear-gradient
linear-gradient
```

you can also try to only use the linear-gradient most of the browsers will support this

```
.title {
    background: linear-gradient(center top , #6F6F6F 0%, #4E4E4E 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

you can also use [this](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to generate the gradient

Comment: i am using meta <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

Comment: @ha1tru0n9, this only detects devices not the browser type

Comment: here your saying that a browser using viewport the zoom scale = 1

Answer (score 2):

`-moz-` is a vendor-specific prefix for Gecko-powered browsers. It will not work in browsers that are not powered by Gecko. The syntax has since been standardized, so on newer browsers, it is no longer necessary to have a vendor prefix at all:

```
background: linear-gradient(red, green);
```

Unfortunately, not everyone has a newer browser, so you often have to include the vendor prefixes *as well*:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, green);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, green);
background: linear-gradient(red, green);
```

Don't get tricked into only using vendor prefixes when the syntax has been standardized.

Comment: Related: http://www.glazman.org/weblog/dotclear/index.php?post/2012/02/09/CALL-FOR-ACTION%3A-THE-OPEN-WEB-NEEDS-YOU-NOW

Answer (score 0):

You should use like :

```
.title {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, from(rgba(255,0,0,1.0)), to(rgba(255,0,0,0.0)));
}
```

These links can help u :

[cross-browser-css-gradient](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient)

[Apple Community Discussion on using Gradient](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1980640?start=0&tstart=0)